# Generating public key instance for JWT validation

Tags: java, kotlin

today we changed on from the HMAC to the RSA on our login server so I have to change the code in our Andoid app to work with that. Problem is when I try to generate a RSA public key instance from a string, all I get is `java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: Error parsing public key` exception and I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

Code I use is pretty simple:

```
val base64KeyString  ="LS0tLS.......BASE 64 PUBLIC KEY STRING..........LRVktLS0tLQ=="
val keySpec = X509EncodedKeySpec(base64KeyString.toByteArray())
val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
val pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec) //<= this is where the exception is thrown
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: It could be a good idea that you first base64**decode** the base64KeyString and use the output as direct input for your "X509EncodedKeySpec"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java crypto uses actual data on its APIs not base64, so as MichaelFehr commented you need to base64-decode your string; in standard Java (8 up) this can be done with `java.util.Base64` but I don't know for Android. But less obviously, your base64 string is wrong -- it is NOT the base64 encoding of a publickey, but rather the encoding of something that begins with 4 bytes with value 2D (which is the character code for hyphen) and ends with 7 bytes which are the character codes for "EY-----" -- in other words, it appears to be the base64 encoding of a slightly broken *PEM file* (that might possibly *encode* a publickey) not an actual publickey structure.

As a working example, given the following keypair represented by the (OpenSSL-compatible and widely used) PEM encodings

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsYU/MoIxYeVuCFcrX+fE
H5XX/he/nJTSQ6P4RF38DKLNnNtQ9XfnaMEPk2EXgSIHk+VXhE9vZNxsV7Emjg6C
+eRxUB1NDBtWGX/Ts2cOYD8ZhSumhOplKKEmdEkzGU/Rem3myfB2BQeN6RSRFigZ
fsR2I4oaQ5YDWJ3uk6Ix0XN4zQwmtw1t9W9tgDZATDLW0+8uU02Wc2HrIcyOvDqJ
DXz/XVY+F+pkrws/ygOhxtVdNY7r3meSKjSUVkOiXMdaqK+20l/YrvoZRVe6HEIT
pu9t/x6YDaoTThsbptjkAKBYpSG2UeXJnnQMyKD2GT3Ouyiupv7lPovvLZZiqfVI
WQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

and a token created on jwt.io, the following (Java) code using jjwt verifies and parses the token:

```
    String pubkeyb64 = // note BEGIN/END lines and linebreaks from PEM removed
            "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsYU/MoIxYeVuCFcrX+fE"+
            "H5XX/he/nJTSQ6P4RF38DKLNnNtQ9XfnaMEPk2EXgSIHk+VXhE9vZNxsV7Emjg6C"+
            "+eRxUB1NDBtWGX/Ts2cOYD8ZhSumhOplKKEmdEkzGU/Rem3myfB2BQeN6RSRFigZ"+
            "fsR2I4oaQ5YDWJ3uk6Ix0XN4zQwmtw1t9W9tgDZATDLW0+8uU02Wc2HrIcyOvDqJ"+
            "DXz/XVY+F+pkrws/ygOhxtVdNY7r3meSKjSUVkOiXMdaqK+20l/YrvoZRVe6HEIT"+
            "pu9t/x6YDaoTThsbptjkAKBYpSG2UeXJnnQMyKD2GT3Ouyiupv7lPovvLZZiqfVI"+
            "WQIDAQAB";
    String jws = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.ry5trgLoSgYZt17NOttSkyFhXIKBHjw3OZy8SK_uwukUCMCSh6O5njlRhTA306lXTFrUkb4VCKYk43y_3vTBDzNA7aAZEuwl0pL2O2gfvvcytXnHsnkjaPiigUvNF-pqpvJkOXhTXobKq-76m7ozHTabxbIO0OM4PTkte_2c2922U22qAFuVmfuKRqr3rsMwp24QImppmWsa_rElSqGhc6wIDGwrtdTIFe311Fi8o7L7wWIswRvH4WlsLG6fLGv6yNt-e2Ld5X1kAfozaZqy-hdR9vpq9LqWVWId6VhJ4kayPVnImevctyMY14TlVlwJdRBBgTAdVVl9QHFbMgwozg";
    byte[] pubkeyder = Base64.getDecoder().decode(pubkeyb64);
    PublicKey pubkey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubkeyder));
    Claims parsed = Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(pubkey).build().parseClaimsJws(jws).getBody();
    System.out.println (parsed);
```

Modification to Kotlin, if you need that, should be trivial.